# Python script for encrypting / decrypting suddenly doesn't work

Tags: python, public-key-encryption

I'm brushing up on public/private keypair encryption. To illustrate the concept to myself, I wrote a primitive script. It used to work just a week ago with my python client:

```
> Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21)  [GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>>
```

Today, I tried to run it, and got the following error:

```
work@work-IdeaPad-U330p:~/projects/Script$ python example_encrypt_decrypt.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_encrypt_decrypt.py", line 9, in <module>
    encrypted_message = public_key_1.encrypt(M, 24)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 123, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attrname)
AttributeError: encrypt
```

The script I'm running is this:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import binascii

private_key_1 = RSA.generate(1024)
public_key_1  = private_key_1.publickey()

M = "Hello World."

encrypted_message = public_key_1.encrypt(M, 24)
# print binascii.hexlify(encrypted_message[0])

# The private key corresponding to the public key used
# to encrypt the message can decrypt the message.
decrypted_message = private_key_1.decrypt(encrypted_message)
print decrypted_message

# The message can not be decrypted with another
# private key.
private_key_2 = RSA.generate(1024)
print private_key_2.decrypt(encrypted_message)
```

Comment: It says that `public_key_1.encrypt` is not a function. Besides, you shouldn't use textbook RSA. You need a padding such as OAEP.

Comment: please don't include leading line numbers when posting code. that makes it only harder if someone wants to paste your code into an interpreter to see what could be wrong.

Comment: Not sure what's going on.  Can you print out some additional information about the public key object before you call encrypt for debugging purposes?  Eg type, attribute values, etc.

Comment: Also what version of the Crypto package?

Comment: @ArtjomB. As I write at the top, this is just to understand the concepts.